# summarise() doesn't recognize a variable

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm wondering why I get `Error: Problem with summarise() input wt_avg` below?

```
library(tidyverse)

CA_vacc <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/2017-2018%20CA%20Vaccination%20Data.csv',
na = c(".","--*"))

CA_vacc %>% summarise(
    wt_avg = sum(HEPB_percent * ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE)
  )


# Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `wt_avg`.
```

Comment: HEPB_percent is a character "783%" for instance. You also have ?99% in the data, which might be their version of NA, I would check the source

Comment: You need to convert to a numeric and do a little preprocessing. `as.numeric(str_remove_all(CA_vacc$HEPB_percent, "\\?|%"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
CA_vacc %>% summarise(
  wt_avg = sum(parse_number(HEPB_percent) * ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE)
+ )
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  wt_avg
   <dbl>
1   96.8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 library(tidyverse)
 CA_vacc  %>%
  mutate(HEPB_percent = as.numeric(str_remove_all(CA_vacc$HEPB_percent, "\\?|%"))) %>%
  summarise(
  wt_avg = sum(HEPB_percent * ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
with(CA_vacc, sum(as.numeric(gsub("[?%]", "", HEPB_percent)) * 
      ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(ENROLLMENT, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 96.76707
```